# Getting: Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: macos, apache, macos-big-sur

```
Mac OS Big Sur - 11.4
```

I am trying to set up some local vhosts. I did the following:

Modified the httpd.conf file, to include the vhosts folder:

```
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/proxy-html.conf
```

And in my /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/proxy-html.conf, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress.com
    DocumentRoot "~/Dropbox/cms/drupal_local"
    ServerName drupal.local
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/drupal.local.error.log"
    CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/drupal.local.access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I then modified the /etc/hosts file as follows:

```
27.0.0.1    localhost drupal.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I made sure I had a folder ~/Dropbox/cms/drupal_local

And in it, I created a simple index.html, that says:

```
<h1>Testing local drupal vhost</h1>
```

I then did:

```
brew services restart httpd
```

And the result was:

```
Stopping `httpd`... (might take a while)
  ==> Successfully stopped `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
  ==> Successfully started `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
```

I then went to my browser, and typed:

```
http://drupal.local
```

And the response was:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First, I don't think you can use `~` in paths in the Apache config -- `~` only expands to your home directory path in certain situations, and I don't think this is one of them (and if it did, it'd expand to something like the `_www` user's home, not yours). Second, check the file permissions on your home directory, and the `Dropbox`, `cms`, and `drupal_local` subfolders -- the `_www` user will need read (and execute/search) access to all of them.

Comment: I am getting a 403, which means the page was found by cannot be accessed. I checked the permissions, and they are the same as the ~/Sites/index.html that shows up properly when I do http://localhost

Comment: Check the perms with `sudo -u _www ls ~/Dropbox/cms/drupal_local`, and see if that can read the directory. If that works, it might be [personal information protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/) (though I don't *think* that'd apply to ~/Dropbox) -- try creating a crontab entry (under your user) like `* * * * * ~/Dropbox/cms/drupal_local >/tmp/permscheck.log 2>&1`, wait a minute, then check that log to see if it worked (and then remove the crontab entry).

Comment: I moved the content to the ~/Sites folder, and it's still not working. I tried listing the directory as _www and it worked. Still getting a 403.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working:

I modified my /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/proxy-html.conf as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress.com
    DocumentRoot "~/Dropbox/cms/drupal_local"
    ServerName drupal.local
    <directory "~/Dropbox/cms/drupal_local/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>    
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/drupal.local.error.log"
    CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/drupal.local.access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and my /etc/hosts file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost 
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1    drupal.local
```

Then:

```
brew services restart httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on MacOS Monterey. Based on the logs, it was caused by an autoindex error.

I fixed it by adding `index.php` to `DirectoryIndex` in `httpd.conf` (path `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` in my case):

```
<IfModule dir_module>
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

(Then of course, restart the service with `brew services restart httpd` for changes to take effect)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue in MacOS Monteray, after days of searching I finally found the solution in the apple forums article:

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250004361